# How can I use $display statement within sequence block, to display some info in System Verilog Assertions (SVAs)?

Tags: system-verilog, vlsi, asic, system-verilog-assertions

I want sequence blocks to display some information, while they are being executed.

e.g.:

```
sequence A;
 a;
 $display ("Signal A asserted here");
endsequence
```

I tried this code, but encountered the following error:

*Task $display is invoked where function is expected.
  Please correct the task call and recompile.*

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

You can invoked a `$display` within sequence expression with the syntax `(sequence_expr, sequence_match_item)` where sequence_match_item can be a operator_assignment, inc_or_dec_expression, or subroutine_call.

```
sequence A;
 (a, $display("Signal A asserted here"));
endsequence
```

Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 16.11 *Calling subroutines on match of a sequence*, which has a direct example of `$display` being invoked within a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "always" block for the $display statements.